# How to run a Makefile in WSL

Tags: matlab, makefile, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I run a Makefile in WSL?

I ran `make -f Makefile` in WSL and received the following error:

```
CFLAGS='-fpic -std=c++17' -R2018a usrp_mex.cpp usrp_gpio.cpp usrp_io.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread `pkg-config --libs --cflags uhd`
/bin/sh: 1: -R2018a: not found
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'usrp_mex.mex' failed
make: *** [usrp_mex.mex] Error 127
```

It seems that the **mex** command cannot be found. How can I add the Matlab installation to **PATH**?

From Makefile:

```
BUILDDIR:=build

MEX=${shell which mex}
ifeq ("$(MEX)", "")
    MEX:=${shell which matlab-mex}
endif

all: usrp_mex.mex 

usrp_mex.mex: usrp_mex.cpp usrp_gpio.cpp usrp_io.cpp
    $(MEX) CFLAGS='-fpic -std=c++17' -R2018a $^ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread `pkg-config --libs --cflags uhd`
```

Comment: Please format the example in your question using code blocks (indent those lines by 4 spaces) rather than just using a fixed-width font.  Your example is all messed up and hard to read.

Comment: Also, please show us the makefile recipe around line 11 in the Makefile

Comment: Apparently the `MEX` make variable is empty, probably because `which mex` and `which matlab-mex` return the empty string. Is one of these utilities installed and in your `PATH`?

Comment: "*How can I add the Matlab installation to PATH?*" -- do you have (Linux) Matlab installed *in* WSL?  A Matlab installation in the host Windows installation is unlikely to suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are literally trying to run:

```
CFLAGS='-fpic -std=c++17' -R2018a usrp_mex.cpp...
```

from the shell.   This line will run the variable assignment, `CFLAGS='-fpic -std=c++17'`, which will set `CFLAGS` to `'-fpic -std=c++17'` (notice the quotes).  This variable will only set for the duration of that recipe line.  The shell will then try to process the next token, `-R2018a`, which it will treat as an executable.

My guess is that the closing quote is misplaced in this recipe line, but you'd have to post the rule to confirm.

Comment: I'm not sure if the quotes are the issue. I think it has something to do with adding Matlab R2018a to the WSL Path? I edited the question and posted the full Makefile.

Comment: The issue is `$(MEX)` is empty.

Comment: @Philippe Is there a way to resolve this? I'm fairly new to Makefiles/WSL so I'm not sure if there is something I need to specify in the WSL command line.

Comment: You can put in your $HOME/.bashrc : `PATH=$PATH:/path-to-matlab/bin` and make sure that you can run `mex` or `matlab-mex` in the terminal.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add the line `export PATH := path-to-matlab/.bin:$(PATH)` to your makefile.  You should also add an explicit check that `$(MEX)` is found, and raise an error if not

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Something like this?
    `BUILDDIR:=build`


    `export PATH := C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/.bin:$(PATH)`

    `MEX=${shell which mex}
        ifeq ("$(MEX)", "")
     MEX:=${shell which matlab-mex}
        endif`

    `all: usrp_mex.mex`

    `usrp_mex.mex: usrp_mex.cpp usrp_gpio.cpp usrp_io.cpp
     $(MEX) CFLAGS='-fpic -std=c++17' -R2018a $^ -lboost_filesystem        
    -lboost_thread `pkg-config --libs --cflags uhd``